# Mass Import connection to other module?

Tags: crm, sugarcrm, suitecrm

In detail view of a module we have a sub-panel with connection to another module.

We created the first module and populated it with import, how would one go about populating the connection by import rather than selecting each manually?

[GFYCat html5gif](https://gfycat.com/DependableRepentantAmericanbittern)

Could one, for example, access the link table in the SQL and import into there? (if so, how?)

Or is there a way built into UI that I've somehow missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sub panel is a many to many relationship. If you look at the database you will see a middle table which you can use to relate the items.

For example accounts has a contacts sub panel. The relationship is kept in accounts_contacts.

Assuming that your references fields contain the same value. In mysql you could an insert statement with a select state the in the where section.

For example you could run an SQL statement like:

```
INSERT INTO blocks_leaseholders (id, blocks_id, leaseholders_id, date_modified, deleted) SELECT GUID(), blocks.id, leaseholders.id, NOW(), '0' JOIN leaseholders ON (blocks.reference = leaseholders.reference) WHERE blocks.reference LIKE leaseholders.reference
```

(I have made some assumptions here so you will need to edit this query)

Comment: They're pretty good assumptions actually.  Reference is identical in both tables and is a relate field

Comment: Really? Cool. The middle table tends to have weird columns for the ids though. So I might have the id's the wrong way round.

Comment: yeah I think so, it calls them ida and idb [Structure](http://i.imgur.com/KrdsQFs.png)

Comment: Sometime related fields use the _cstm table instead. So it would be the blocks_cstm you need to insert into.

Comment: Do you really need to sub panels with the same name? If was a single sub panel the id's would be ..._blocks_ida - blocks id and ..._leaseholders_idb - the leaseholders id.

Comment: it was calling an error on that, but there is no cstm for my lhb_leaseholders.

http://imgur.com/noKNf6N&MP7Zgql&0QMhRhm&geuSX5o

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107958/discussion-between-thegeorgel-and-daniel-samson).

Comment: This is only good for historic data. For future records you would have to clear the middle table and run the SQL again.